# Sending files from one pc to another using python code

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a pythoncode to send a file (lets assume that the file name is 'frog' and it is located in C:/ drive ) from one  pc to another.
Let assume that both pc's Bluetooth is turned on.
Is there a code to do this ?
If yes can you please share ?

Comment: Just curious, why not scp or ftp? why via python?

Comment: https://guide.freecodecamp.org/python/share-file-using-python-simple-http-server/

Comment: Do you wan to transfer via bluetooth?? If it's on same network then you have the IP and you can do scp or sftp as suggested by @UpasanaMittal. There are many modules available for that. You can even run native command. But as you are in windows, native command won't work

Comment: @UpasanaMittal because I am a novice and python is the first language I am learning . Thanks for the article .

Comment: hope that article helped you